# Play framework and SBT fail to override configuration with ENV variable

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

For some reason i fail to override a property in my configuration file when running tests with SBT.

Note that when I run the tests with IntelliJ and set the environment variable from there, the configuration file value is being overridden properly.

Here is what i am doing

application.conf:

> ```
>   mongodb.uri = "mongodb://mongodb:27017/"
>   mongodb.uri = ${?MONGO_URI}
> ```

In my SBT file I have:

> ```
> fork in run := false
> fork in test := false
> ```

And I run the tests like so:

```
sbt -DMONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost:27018/ clean test
```

But that doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a java option for test like this:

```
javaOptions in test += "-DMONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost:27018/"
```